# How does reloading and ammo work with CthulhuTech mecha?

Tags: weapons, mecha, cthulhutech

In CthulhuTech, how do mecha weapons work with regards to ammo and reloading ? For example, a Laser Cannon has 3 shots and infinite rounds. Does this mean that it needs to spend a full turn reloading after firing 3 shots ? And/or does it mean that the pilot needs to spend an action to reload it ?

By contrast, rocket pods can hold 10 or 20 rockets. What happens when the pilot runs out of rockets ? Does his mecha hold more ordnance that can be reloaded, or is that all he gets until he can resupply back at the base ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These weapons operate differently. The laser uses a rate of fire, and the rocket pod uses ammunition. This information is detailed in charts and their explanatory text in Chapter 10 of the CthulhuTech core rules, on pages 148 and 149.

### Rate of Fire

The laser cannon is an energy weapon. It does not use ammunition, it has a rate of fire. Where it lists 3 shots it is stating the number of shots which can be fired in one round by the pilot. If the pilot chooses to use actions to shoot multiple times, they can use that weapon up to a maximum of 3 times in that single round. This provides an interesting tactical decision concerning how to use the available actions in a round.

### Ammunition

The rocket pod does use ammunition and that ammunition can be depleted. The pod holds a maximum number of rockets. Once all of those rockets have been launched, the pod is empty and will need to be reloaded back at the base, or some other resupply location.

The pilot can control the speed at which they use up their ammunition as rocket pods utilize a rack system which allows the pilot to launch salvos of rockets of different quantities, either in flights of 2 missiles or flights of 5 missiles. This provides an interesting tactical decision between greater endurance for the weapon or greater damage output per shot.